# How can i get the content of an html.Node

Tags: html-parsing, go

I would like to get data from a URL using the `GO` 3rd party library from http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.net/html . But I came across a problem, that is I couldn't get the content of an html.Node.

There's an example code in the reference document, and here's the code.

```
s := `<p>Links:</p><ul><li><a href="foo">Foo</a><li><a href="/bar/baz">BarBaz</a></ul>`
doc, err := html.Parse(strings.NewReader(s))
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
var f func(*html.Node)
f = func(n *html.Node) {
    if n.Type == html.ElementNode && n.Data == "a" {
        for _, a := range n.Attr {
            if a.Key == "href" {
                fmt.Println(a.Val)
                break
            }
        }
    }
    for c := n.FirstChild; c != nil; c = c.NextSibling {
        f(c)
    }
}
f(doc)
```

The output is:

```
foo
/bar/baz
```

If I want to get

```
Foo
BarBaz
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The tree of `<a href="link"><strong>Foo</strong>Bar</a>` looks basically like this:

- ElementNode "a" (this node also includes a list off attributes)

  - ElementNode "strong"

    - TextNode "Foo"
  - TextNode "Bar"

So, assuming that you want to get the plain text of the link (e.g. `FooBar`) you would have to walk trough the tree and collect all text nodes. For example:

```
func collectText(n *html.Node, buf *bytes.Buffer) {
    if n.Type == html.TextNode {
        buf.WriteString(n.Data)
    }
    for c := n.FirstChild; c != nil; c = c.NextSibling {
        collectText(c, buf)
    }
}
```

And the changes in your function:

```
var f func(*html.Node)
f = func(n *html.Node) {
    if n.Type == html.ElementNode && n.Data == "a" {
        text := &bytes.Buffer{}
        collectText(n, text)
        fmt.Println(text)
    }
    for c := n.FirstChild; c != nil; c = c.NextSibling {
        f(c)
    }
}
```